# Use Avro as the Data Format for Outbox Pattern using MySQL Debezium Connector

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, avro, debezium, outbox-pattern

I am using debezium MySQL to achieve outbox pattern. In my payload column, I am using Avro and I convert Avro into byte so that I can store the avro data into MySQL database. If I want to do the schema evolution in the future, I am wondering where should I keep my schema? Should I store the writer schema as a separate column in my outbox table? Or, is there a better way? Thank you so much!!

Comment: I am wondering about this as well. Did you find a solution that worked for you?